# Can't read fields from previous step, kettle

Tags: field, pentaho, kettle

I have a small problem in kettle. These are the steps I'm using.
[kettle rocks http://imageshack.com/a/img22/7915/ffk9.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img22/7915/ffk9.png)

The error is at the second step saying that it's unable to get fields from the previous step because of an error, but the sql in "Table input" step works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you preview the `Table Input` step? If that gives an error, let us know what it is?

Comment: You will need to post some more details. I've seen `User Defined Java Class`es that comprise of hundreds of code rows, it could be essentially anything. I would start by adding the log entries to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this version of mysql java connector(mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar). This worked for me, hope will work for you.